# Facing this issue while predicting "CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted"

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

```
#these are classifier and  vectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer = spacy_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,1))
classifier = LinearSVC()
```

I have created a Pipeline as shown below

```
# Create the  pipeline to clean, tokenize, vectorize, and classify
pipe = Pipeline([("cleaner", predictors()),
                 ('vectorizer', vectorizer),
                  ('classifier', classifier)])
```

while predicting the test dataset, im facing this issue.

```
sample_prediction = pipe.predict(X_test)
```

## ERROR : sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give your training set to the model to be trained

```
_= pipe.fit(triningSet.data, triningSet.target)
```

I don't see any training dataset here. you have to fit the `CountVectoriser` to your data set.